# How to choose eclipse update site mirror server in Eclipse IDE e.g. Sweden, Japan etc

Tags: updates, plugins, eclipse

While trying to install a new plugin in Eclipse, it seems to take a lot of time with the default mirror site being chosen by Eclipse. Is there any way, where I can set which mirror location to use while updating Eclipse or installing a new plugin ?

(while installing a new plugin, eclipse seems to check for dependency libraries and I think it downloads from default chosen location)

Answer (score 1):

That issue is reported on the [Eclipse Bugs](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/) page:

[Bug 256909 - P2 mirrorApplication should have an option to set the local mirror name](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=256909)

The patch can be found here:

[[patch] Allso users to set destination repository name](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=119784&action=edit)

---

Additionally, there's this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/349026/352449) to the same issue!

Comment: I still didn't found a way to select the update site. Can you mention the steps required. I am using latest version of Eclipse JUNOS.